# add a serial number while performing iteration in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, web, thymeleaf

I have a senario in which i must perform iteration on a list and display result as a grid.Also include serial number in it. Now what I did for serial number is given below

```
<div th:with="i=0">
 <tr th:each="mydate:${data.Listdata}" >
  <div th:with="i=${i+1}">
   <td th:text="${i}">
  </div>
    //other codes
 </tr>
</div>
```

but only 1 appears in all serial number.Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the index of the iteration status:

```
<tr th:each="item,iterator : ${items}">
    <td th:text="${iterator.index}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: <td th:text="${iterator.index}"></td>

Answer (score 4):

You can use the iterationStatus to begin with 1 instead of 0.

```
 <tr th:each="item,iterationStatus : ${items}">
    <td th:text=${iterationStatus.count}></td>
 </tr>
```

This gives the table Sno. Starting with 1.
You may visit https://www.ansiboug.com/2023/07/add-serial-number-while-performing.html for more details.

Comment: Just to clarify this answer: Using the `count` property instead of `index` property gives us numbers starting with 1 instead of 0. We are free to use any name for the `iterationStatus` variable. Whatever name we assign to second argument in `th:each`, same must be used inside the loop to access these iterator status properties.

Comment: it has been helpful @rineez

Answer (score 0):

To get the index:

```
<tr th:each="item: ${items}">
    <td th:text="${iterator.indexOf(item)}"></td>
</tr>
```

To get a numbering increment index by one.

```
 <tr th:each="item: ${items}">
    <td th:text="${iterator.indexOf(item) + 1}"></td>
</tr>
```